# Kernel of the dual isogeny

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am currently working on elliptic curves (over finite fields), and I asked myself the following question.

> Let $\phi:E \longrightarrow E'$ be an isogeny and $\hat \phi:E'
>  \longrightarrow E$ the corresponding dual isogeny. Is it true that
>   $\ker(\phi)\cong\ker(\hat\phi)$ ?

I don't see any obvious reason why this should be true, and in fact it feels like it's not but I can't prove it. I just need a yes/no answer, but a proof is also welcome.

Furthermore we may suppose that we're working over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, and the order of the isogeny is a prime power $l^a$ coprime to the characteristic of the field. Also the kernel of $\phi$ is cyclic and $E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})\cong E'(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$, but both $E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ and $E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ contain the $l^a$ torsion so it doesn't exclude the possibility that $\ker(\hat\phi)\cong C_{l^{a/2}}\times C_{l^{a/2}}$ or something else non-cyclic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E$ be an ordinary elliptic curve over $\Bbb F_p$.
Let $E'=E$ and $\phi$ be the Frobenius map. Then $\ker\phi$
is trivial. But $\hat\phi\circ\phi=[p]$ which has kernel of order $p$
(since $E$ is ordinary) so $\ker\hat\phi$ has order $p$.

For isogenies of degree coprime to the characteristic, the kernels
are isomorphic.

Comment: _For isogenies of degree coprime to the characteristic, the kernels are isomorphic._ Even in the supersingular case over an extension field?

Comment: @Kolja: Being supersingular only concerns the $p$-primary torsion, where $p$ is the characteristic of the field. If the isogeny is of degree coprime to the characteristic (so $p$), then the above holds.

Comment: In general (even in the supersingular case) there is an identification of $\ker(\widehat{\phi})$ with the Cartier dual of $\ker(\phi)$. This allows you to understand the structure of $\ker(\widehat{\phi})$ as a group together with its corresponding action of $\mathrm{Gal}(k^{sep}/k)$.